# iOS Universal Links: What comes first - `didFinishLaunching` or `continue userActivity`

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios-universal-links

This question is about iOS Universal Links.

My `UIApplicationDelegate` implementation features 2 implemented methods:

- [application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application)
- [application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623072-application)

The question is: which will be called first when I open my unlaunched app using a valid universal link?

Comment: This method is not called if either `application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` or `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` returns `false`.

So based on that - `will/didFinish` will be first

Comment: @VitaliiShvetsov dude, might as well post this as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of the second method says: This method is not called if either `application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` or `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` returns false. So based on that - `will/didFinish` will be first